# Fear of an effect occurring causing the effect

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

For example a fear of not making a good impression on people causing a person to be paranoid of people's opinions and thus not making a good impression on them.

Is this situational irony or something else? I feel like it is, but when looking it up I only see mention of the opposite of the expectation occurring. In this situation the expected outcome is making a good impression, but more specifically the expectation is causing the opposite to occur as opposed to it being out of the person's control.

The sentence I'm trying to use the word in:

> [Ironically] my fear of burning bridges resulted in my paranoia, which is the most bridge burning effect I have exhibited.

Comment: *Self-fulfilling prophecy* : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-fulfilling_prophecy

Comment: @Josh61 Is there an adverb for that? I'd like to start a sentence with something like Ironically.

Comment: @Docopoper - Could  you edit your question to include a sample sentence. You could put a blank where the word should go. It's easier if we see some context. Thanks

Comment: Inevitably? perhaps

Comment: A famous case where some people argue this happened is with Job (Job 3:25)  _What I feared has come upon me_ [NIV], though the cause-and-effect process is not easy to see.

Comment: It's called "superstition".

Comment: This is kind of a stretch, but the word "iatrogenic" describes an illness caused by a physician while trying to treat an illness.  I guess the adverbial form of that would be "iatrogenically".

Comment: As an alternative to self-fulfilling prophecy, one could say it's a *vicious circle*.  The fear of making a bad impression leads to making a bad impression, which only increases the fear, which makes the next impression even worse, which ....

Comment: @Hot Licks: Not always. If the most likely reason you might fail your driving test is that you'll be *nervous*, the mere fact of worrying about this might actually cause you to be nervous on the day, and *consequently* fail. I know, because it just happened to my daughter a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: It's too bad that "Oedipal avoidance" got commandeered by Freud, because it would be a perfect descriptive term for what the OP is talking about: multiple people in the story of Oedipus try to avoid their fate by taking steps that seem to move them away from that fate—only to make it come true in every detail.

Comment: I am not sure that there is there a self-contradiction, i.e. a **Paradox**. We may then replace "Ironically" by "**Paradoxically**".

Comment: Why is paranoia a "bridge burning effect"?

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t much irony in *my fear of burning bridges resulted in my paranoia* because there is no general expectation that fear should prevent the feared outcome. So *ironically* does not work there. *Predictably* or *unsurprisingly* would probably be more accurate.

There is no question that you’re talking of a self-fulfilling fear. As you want an adverb, you may want to know that, even though I wasn't able to find it in a dictionary, [***self-fulfillingly*** has been used before](https://www.google.pt/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22self-fulfillingly%22&tbm=bks&start=0) in the sense you want (as opposed to self-satisfying) in a number of books, albeit very rarely. Here’s an example:

> In short, attempts to institute alcohol-free social activities or institutions may fail to generate support because students mistakenly (and *self-fulfillingly*) assume they will not be widely supported. ([Arie W. Kruglanski and E. Tory Higgins (editors), *Social Psychology, A General Reader*, 2003, p. 599.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=AafceHGT-vQC&pg=PA599&dq=%22self-fulfillingly%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX6v7kssfJAhXJfhoKHZN5DBg4ChDoAQhGMAg#v=onepage&q=%22self-fulfillingly%22&f=false))

Then you may want to consider ***fatefully***, from [***fateful***](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/fateful):

> having an important, especially bad, effect on future events

Now *fatefully* only implies that the fear will have a bad effect on future events, not that the bad effect is the feared outcome itself, but in context this is quite evident.

Comment: Most often (in the US) referred to as "self-fulfilling prophecy".

Comment: @HotLicks Indeed. I've never heard anybody say *self-fulfilling fear* myself. But I just thought it was a more exact description of what the OP was talking about. Fulfilling a fear sounds a bit strange though.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than *irony* it's perhaps [*portent*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/portent) -

> something that foreshadows a coming event :  omen, sign

...so you could use ***portentously***, as foreshadowed by the suggestion in the comments of self-fulfilling *prophesy*, though with less definite an actor than *prophetically*, and not as gloomy as *ominously*.

However in your sample sentence I might just switch it to the less dramatic and less pretentious [***tellingly***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tellingly):

> carrying great weight and producing a marked effect

As the line sounds introspective, *tellingly* seems fitting to me.  But if the subsequent events are a bit dramatic, *portentously* would work just fine.